# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'component')

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel, vue.js

У меня возникла ошибка в Vue.js.

Вот сама ошибка:

```
calculator.js:19439 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'component')
    at ./resources/assets/js/calculator.js (calculator.js:19439:45)
    at __webpack_require__ (calculator.js:44876:42)
    at calculator.js:45047:83
    at __webpack_require__.O (calculator.js:44913:23)
    at calculator.js:45050:53
    at calculator.js:45052:12
./resources/assets/js/calculator.js @ calculator.js:19439
__webpack_require__ @ calculator.js:44876
(anonymous) @ calculator.js:45047
__webpack_require__.O @ calculator.js:44913
(anonymous) @ calculator.js:45050
(anonymous) @ calculator.js:45052
calculator.css:1     GET https://growexspeak.space/img
```

Также предоставляю мой код

```
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

// import './bootstrap';

import Vue from 'vue'
window.Vue = Vue;
/**
 * The following block of code may be used to automatically register your
 * Vue components. It will recursively scan this directory for the Vue
 * components and automatically register them with their "basename".
 *
 * Eg. ./components/ExampleComponent.vue -> <example-component></example-component>
 */

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/Example.vue').default);
Vue.component('calculator', require('./components/Calculator.vue').default);

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#calculator'
});
```

Буду благодарен за решения проблемы.

Comment: Вы уверены что ошибка не в компоненте calculator? Она либо у него в коде. либо тут `require('./components/Calculator.vue').default` require не находит компонент